# using input from dropdown menu to create another dropdown menu

Tags: php

On a page written in php I want to do following:

Dropdown menu with number from 1 to 12 > After user selects number x, x more dropdown menus (with different options) will appear.
This is what I used so far but I have no idea how to make it work.

```
$steps = array (
    1 => '1',
    2 => '2',
    3 => '3',
    4 => '4',
    5 => '5',
    6 => '6',
    7 => '7',
    8 => '8',
    9 => '9',
    10 => '10',
    11 => '11',
    12 => '12',
);

$events = array (
    'Click' => 'Click',
    'Create' => 'Create',
    'Download' => 'Download',
    'Load' => 'Load',
    'Login' => 'Login',
    'Payment' => 'Payment',
    'Promocode' => 'Promocode',
    'Registration' => 'Registration',
    'Remove' => 'Remove',
    'Restart' => 'Restart',
    'Start' => 'Start',
    'View' => 'View',
);

$form['steps'] = array (
    '#prefix' => '<div class="regionsel form-item">',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select number of steps'),
    '#default_value' => isset($_GET['step']) ? >input_filter($_GET['step']) : '1',
    '#options' => $steps,
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

Comment: PHP is a [server side language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming); if you want to do something dynamic on the front-end you'll need a client side language, e.g. JavaScript

Comment: How would I go about that? How should I make JS code that does the same?

Comment: Create your first dropdown, bind an onchange event to it that calls a function that spawns the other dropdowns... answering this in detail would be too broad for StackOverflow though I think; I'd suggest trying some things out (maybe look at [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)) and come back when you're stuck on a specific piece of code.